# Flash stock ROM on Amlogic Android Smart TV Box

Tags: rom-flashing, installation, smart-tv

I have a Amlogic S805 Quad Core TV Box - which went "south" on me during a ROM update. I tried to reset it, but then noticed the reset button had come away from the internals. I managed to get it to the flash screen via SD Card, but it says it - "*cannot be mounted, as the folders do not exist*".

How can I put the Android ROM onto the flash drive of this box - tried to connect via a USB lead - but my PC will not pick up the box at all.

Comment: I removed the specs since I don't think it will help solving the issue (you can still check the specs on the [original revision](http://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/133298/1)). Also, this seems to be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please clarify the real question, instead of asking how to do your proposed approach.

Comment: I need to re-instate the original ROM on my TV Box, and need to know a way to connect to the box - or find out why the SD Card is failing to mount